# ExecuteReader: la propiedad Connection no se ha inicializado en IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, iis, hosting

Primeramente tengo el sitio web asp.net funcionando correctamente en el visual studio 2015,quiero subir el sitio web al IIS(internet information services)
lo subo, hago la prueba y me muestra la pagina correctamente que es un login.
ahora cuando me logueo realizo una consulta sql. y dentro del iis es cuando me bota el siguiente error:
[image: error que sale al momento de loguearse]

dentro del visual studio, no me sale ese error y me logueo correctamente, pero por alguna razón el iis,me muestra este error.
he verificado la cadena de conexión dentro del iis y al parecer esta bien.
les dejo mi clase conexión que utiliza mi sitio para acceder al sql-server.

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;

    /// <summary>
    /// Descripción breve de Conexion
    /// </summary>
    public class Conexion
    {
    protected SqlDataReader reader;
    protected SqlDataAdapter AdaptadorDatos;
    protected DataSet data;



    public Conexion()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Agregar aquí la lógica del constructor
        //
    }

    public SqlConnection Conectar()      
    {
        SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            string strConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["inventarioConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            oconexion.ConnectionString = strConexion;
            oconexion.Open();
            return oconexion;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }


    }

    public bool Validar(string tabla)
    {
        SqlCommand consulta = new SqlCommand(tabla);
        consulta.Connection = this.Conectar();
        SqlDataReader reader = consulta.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
    public bool EjecutarComando(string sql)
    {// inserciones modificaciones y eliminaciones
        SqlConnection cone = this.Conectar();
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(sql, cone);
        if (comando.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Como datos adicionales agrego que estoy trabajando en windows 10, el IIS 10.0.14393.0 Y como es obvio en C#.

Comment: En tu método conectar está ocurriendo una exepción cuando se usa Validar pero como tienes un catch return null, no aparece el error original. Prueba borrando el try catch para ver el error original pero me imagino a que no está encontando la cadena de conexión inventarioConnectionString o hay algún problema de permisos.

Comment: el error no esta en el codigo porque compila perfectamente en el visual studio. pero por alguna razon el servidor iis no puede leer la base de datos.que metodos o formas para subir el sitio al iis me recomiendan..(si tienen alguna experiencia por favor compartanla)

Comment: Compila porque el error ocurre en tiempo de ejecución, no de compilación. Prueba quitando el try catch o logeando la excepcion que ocurre en el método conectar.

Comment: me sale lo siguiente: No se puede abrir la base de datos "inventario" solicitada por el inicio de sesión. Error de inicio de sesión.
Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'WORKGROUP\MARCO$'. Línea 31:             string strConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["inventarioConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
Línea 32:             oconexion.ConnectionString = strConexion;
Línea 33:             oconexion.Open();
Línea 34:             return oconexion;
Línea 35:

Comment: El problema se debe a que probablemente estés usando autenticación integrada. Tienes 2 opciones, o habilitas al usuario MARCO para que tenga acceso a la base de datos o usas autenticación sql usando un usuario y password.

Answer (score 0):

IIS no tien acceso a la base de datos que indicas en la cadena de conexión, desde tu equipo en modo debug puede funcionar, pero fuera de ese entorno no.

Comprueba que las credenciales son correctas y puedes acceder, por ejemplo desde SQL Management Studio

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: muchas gracias por compartir ese link, ya halle la solucion tras realizar una investigacion sobre como funciona sql. el error estaba en dar acceso de lectura y escritura al usuario IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool. y otras configuraciones mas. en las proximas horas subo como lo resolvi. por mala suerte toque cosas que no debi con el Internet information services y ya no funciona mi ip de manera correcta, asi que supongo que tendre que desinstalarlo y volverlo a instalar

Comment: En un entorno de producción depende de las operacines que desees realizar sobre las carpetas, que pueden estar o no en el mismo directorio que la aplicación: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities es diferente de conectar a un servidor sql externo en un puerto determinado o en el propio host con una instancia local en la que debes asegurar la conetividad al puerto 1433 (por defecto). Si se trata de la carpeta APP_DATA el usuario debe poder escribir en la misma, habitualmente con IUSR_ y/o el usuario del pool.

Comment: gracias por la info, pero por el momento estaba en un entorno experimental, quiero empezar por lo mas basico. les dejo tambien otra solucion en el siguiente link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361137/sql-server-error-in-iis-asp-net-web-page